# How does changing to another Public DNS server work?

Tags: networking, dns

I tried following [this guide](https://www.dropbox.com/s/go4dx40zp0vt7wb/RANT0001_a.pdf?dl=0) from Rackspace, but the `/etc/resolv.conf` file that needs editing looks like this, with a very interesting warning:

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

I got the Google DNS settings [from here](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using), but I don't know what to do.

[image]

Do I populate the "Search Domains" field with Google's DNS data, or where should I put it?

Comment: You don't need Google's *search domains*. Search domains are domains automatically appended to names if the system couldn't resolve them (for example, with a search domain `foo.bar`, if `xyz` doesn't resolve, the system will look for `xyz.foo.bar`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your picture, there's a field called **DNS Servers**.

In that text field, replace anything that already exists with this:

```
8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4
```

If you have IPv6, use this instead:

```
8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4, 2001:4860:4860::8888, 2001:4860:4860::8844
```

Both Google's IPv4 and IPv6 addresses have records for both IPv4 and IPv6, so it's a good idea to fall back to the IPv4-only record, because you don't lose anything. You should *not* use only the IPv6 records, because you lose the ability to fall back to IPv4 if something goes wrong.

As for [search domain](https://superuser.com/questions/184361/what-is-the-search-domains-field-for-in-the-tcp-ip-dns-settings-control-panel), if you don't know what to put there, you don't need to set it. If you're on a corporate network, ask your sysadmin.

Hit Save and the new DNS settings will take effect.

Comment: And select `Automatic (DHCP) Addresses Only` instead of Manual.